# Numbers divide its prime factors' concatenation

Tags: number-theory

Check these out!  $$28749=3\cdot 7\cdot 37\cdot 37\; \text{ and } \;28749\mid 373737$$(amazing!).

Even much more interesting than that is this number (because the digits in its prime factors looked very diverge unlike that 373737):   $$21757820799=3\cdot 11\cdot 13\cdot 683\cdot 74257 \;\text{ and } \;21757820799\mid 3111368374257$$  (amazing !!).

Note that that prime factors must be arranged from smaller to larger. Can you find another(composite) number with the same property as the number being mentioned the last ?

Comment: I think we have to go bruteforce.

Comment: "Can you find another number with the same property?" - Yes, every prime number does, so perhaps just add this restriction to the question.

Comment: This is a stupid observation..anyway, we must at least require that the number is odd. We cannot find such even numbers.

Answer (score 3):

If you reverse the arrangement of the factors in the concatenation, there are slightly more of these below $10^{10}$. For example, $378 = 2 \times 3^3 \times 7$ and $378|73332$. The other known numbers with this property are $12467, 95823, 10715274, 13485829, 111495095$.

Paolo P. Lava was wondering about these last year (see [A248915 in Sloane's OEIS](http://oeis.org/A248915)). He also searched for the numbers you have found, but up to $13 \times 10^7$ he could only find $28749$ (which is how I was able to find out about the numbers with the opposite sorting). So he'd probably be happy to hear about $21757820799$.

Answer (score 3):

The next such number you desire is 
$$
  4373079629403 = 3 \times 367 \times 2713 \times 1464031
$$ 
(discovered by Giovanni Resta ?), and this number is clearly what you are waiting for.